# What are the terminal Store Kit transaction states in iOS?

Tags: ios, transactions, in-app-purchase, storekit

Which of the following four possible transaction states are regarded as terminal and after which one would need to call PaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction...?

- SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchasing
- SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed
- SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased
- SKPaymentTransactionState.Restored

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking at it wrong.
It's not the state of the payment queue you should worry about per say, but the notifications you are supposed to handle.

The obvious answer to your question would be -finishTransaction on

1. Failed
2. Purchased
3. Restored

But this answer would hide **key steps** with the transaction:

1. Is your app actually *done* with it? Did you permanently grant the user its purchases?
2. Did you *verify the receipt* and approve the transaction?

Also, I am a bit worried about the `PaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction`. All the methods in `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` pass the `SKPaymentQueue *` to you as one of the parameter. That is what you should use, as exemplified below:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
    updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

Comment: An answer would not be complete without mentioning that in order to win an uphill battle against `StoreKit`, it would be to your advantage to capitalize on clever wrapper libraries, such as [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into RMSTore.